# how to make non-bold text in Elfeed?

Tags: fonts, customize, elfeed

I want search-title-face to be non-bold.

Tried to add to my *.emacs* file this chunk (due to http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/11/26/):

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(elfeed-search-title-face
   ((t :weight normal))))
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the face-attribute to customize. Worked fine for myself :)

```
(set-face-attribute 'elfeed-search-unread-title-face
                      nil
                      :weight 'normal
                      :foreground (face-attribute 'default :foreground))
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does?